# how to delete object in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello:

I have a question about how to delete object in gazebo. I am able to use: "gzfactory spawn -f model.sdf" to spawn object but I don't know how to delete object using a command instead of using GUI and right click to delete the object. Anybody know how to do that? Thanks!

Best wishes
Cherry

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1803/how-to-delete-object-in-gazebo/) by [Cherry](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/262/cherry/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Try:

gzfactory delete -m model_name

where model_name is the name of the model you want to delete

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cherry](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/262/cherry/) on 2013-03-14**:
HI, thanks. I have another question. Because I am doing this in a loop. So I would like the model to be spawned and deleted multiple time. After I spawned the object twice, then I cannot deleted in the scene, although on the left in the model list, the object's name disappeared there. Do you know how to do the delete and spawn multiple times?

**Comment by [Cherry](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/262/cherry/) on 2013-03-14**:
HI, I just figured out it was the rendering problem. I don't actually need to see the object in the scene as long as it exists in the collision model.

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-03-15**:
@iche033
How it is possible to delete model from launched ROS gazebo package? Because it crashes on deleting last model